# Disable authentication and csrf for a given path in Spring Weblux?

Tags: spring-security, kotlin, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux, csrf-protection

I would like to enable oauth2 for the whole application except one url.

My configuration:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity) =
        http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/devices/**/register").permitAll()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login().and()
            .build()
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id: ...
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret: ...
```

All the paths are being protected with oauth2 but the problem is that when I call an endpoint that is permitted `/devices/123/register` then in response I get:

`CSRF Token has been associated to this client`

Do I need to configure this path in a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`permitAll` is a statement about authority only--all the typical web application vulns are still mitigated like XSS and CSRF.

If you are trying to indicate that `/devices/**/register` should be ignored by Spring Security entirely, then you can do:

```
http
    .securityMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
        pathMatchers("/devices/**/register")))
    ... omit the permitAll statement
```

But, if you still want that endpoint to get the secure response headers, just not CSRF protection, then you can do:

```
http
    .csrf()
        .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
            pathMatchers("/devices/**/register")))
    ... keep the permitAll statement
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to disable csrf, you can´t override the securityFilterChain default behaviour.

In my case, I needed to copy the default configuration of springSecurityFilterChain and add csrf configuration as:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain csrfFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeExchange((exchange) -> exchange.anyExchange().authenticated());
        http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        http.oauth2Client(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```