# CSRF enabled on spring cloud gateway does not allow login api POST rest call

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, csrf, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a api gateway to my rest api micro service. the gateway is implemented using the spring cloud gateway project. I want to enable CSRF on the api gateway. I used the below code provided in the documentation to enable it.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
            // ...
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()));
    return http.build();
}
```

To log in to my app, the GUI makes a POST api request to my rest web service, which goes through the api gateway. This call is blocked with the message "An expected CSRF token cannot be found".

So I wanted to permit only the login request and hence made the changes as below.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
            // ...
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
            .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll();
    return http.build();
}
```

now when I restart my application, it does not go to my landing page, instead provides its own log in page.
[image]

Below is my entire configuration. I have angular running my GUI.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class NettyConfiguration implements 
WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

@Value("${server.max-initial-line-length:65536}")
private int maxInitialLingLength;
@Value("${server.max-http-header-size:65536}")
private int maxHttpHeaderSize;

public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory container) {
    container.addServerCustomizers(
            httpServer -> httpServer.httpRequestDecoder(
                    httpRequestDecoderSpec -> {
                        httpRequestDecoderSpec.maxHeaderSize(maxHttpHeaderSize);
                        httpRequestDecoderSpec.maxInitialLineLength(maxInitialLingLength);
                        return httpRequestDecoderSpec;
                    }
            )
    );
}

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
            // ...
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
            .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll();
    return http.build();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Disable authentication and csrf for a given path in Spring Weblux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408961/disable-authentication-and-csrf-for-a-given-path-in-spring-weblux).

The gist of it is that authorizeRequests() does not care about csrf. You should use requireCsrfProtectionMatcher instead to which urls would be subject to CORS verification

Comment: It worked, i am able to avoid csrf to certain paths